# How to change code so that it sends location on request instead of on change

Tags: kotlin, location

Good day. I have receiver some code. From what I understand is it only receives location updates if you location changes. However I would like to get the current location on request rather then when the location changes.
My calling method:

```
LocationHelper().startListeningUserLocation(this , object : LocationHelper.MyLocationListener {
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                lat = location.latitude
                long = location.longitude
                Log.d("Location","" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude)
            }
        })
```

Sub-class:

```
class LocationHelper {
    val LOCATION_REFRESH_TIME = 3000 
    val LOCATION_REFRESH_DISTANCE = 30 
    val MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 100

    var myLocationListener: MyLocationListener? = null

    interface MyLocationListener {
        fun onLocationChanged(location: Location)
    }

    fun startListeningUserLocation(context: Context, myListener: MyLocationListener) {
        myLocationListener = myListener

        val mLocationManager = context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE) as LocationManager

        val mLocationListener = object : LocationListener {
            override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
                //your code here
                myLocationListener!!.onLocationChanged(location) // calling listener to inform that updated location is available
            }
            override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
            override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
            override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
        }

}
```

Above I can change the parameters of when to receive updates. Sadly I do not know this code well enough to change it to on request.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the following website I found a solution: https://techpassmaster.com/get-current-location-in-android-studio-using-kotlin/